# What is the integral range of the $\int_{1}^{4}\int_{\max\left\{\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{2}\right\}}^{\min\left\{\frac{8}{y},{y}\right\}} f(x,y)dxdy$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{1}^{4}\int_{\max\left\{\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{2}\right\}}^{\min\left\{\frac{8}{y},{y}\right\}} \frac{y}{x}\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}+xy\right)dxdy$$

I'm trying to find this value through integration by substitution with $u=\frac{y}{x}$ and $v=xy$.
As I expected the solution found that with the same idea of mine. But the problem is occurred when it comes to the "range of the integral". Focusing the range of the $x$, $x \geq {\max\left\{\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{2}\right\}}$ and $x\leq {\min\left\{\frac{8}{y},{y}\right\}}$.

In other words, I could organizing like the below

$x \geq {\max\{\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{2}\}} \iff (x\geq \frac{1}{y}) \cup (x\geq \frac{y}{2}) \iff (xy\geq 1) \cup (2x\geq y) $

$x\leq {\min\{\frac{8}{y},{y}\}}$ $\iff (x\leq \frac{8}{y}) \cup (x\leq y) \iff (xy\leq8) \cup (x\leq y) $

Therefore, The range of the integral should be $((xy\geq 1) \cup (2x\geq y) )\cap ((xy\leq8) \cup (x\leq y))$and $1 \leq y\leq 4$.

By the distributive law, for the red parts

$\color{red}{(xy\geq 1)\cup (2x\geq y) )} \cap ((xy\leq8) \cup (x\leq y))$ = $(\color{red}{(xy\geq 1) \cup (2x\geq y)} \cap (xy\leq8)) \cup( \color{red}{(xy\geq 1) \cup (2x\geq y)} \cap (x\leq y)) $

$ = (1\leq xy \leq 8 \cup 2x\geq y) \cup  (xy\geq1 \cup x \leq y\leq 2x)$

Hence the range of the integration are $(xy\geq 1 \cup y\geq x)$ with the $1\leq y \leq4$.

But the answer sheet said, $(1\leq xy \leq 8) \cap (1\leq \frac{y}{x} \leq 2)$ is the range of that. I can't understand why the range should that be. Please let me know What I've missed. Plus, please show me  the process deducing  the answer  $(1\leq xy \leq 8) \cap (1\leq \frac{y}{x} \leq 2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ f(y)=\max\bigg\{\frac1y,\frac y2\bigg\}, g(y)= \min\bigg\{\frac8y,y\bigg\}. $$
Letting $\frac1y=\frac y2$ gives $y=\sqrt2$. So
$$ f(y)=\bigg\{\begin{array}{rl}\frac1y & \text{ if }y\in[1,\sqrt2],\\
\frac y2 & \text{ if } y\in(\sqrt2,4].
\end{array}$$.
Similarly letting $\frac8y=y$ gives $y=2\sqrt2$. So
$$ f(y)=\bigg\{\begin{array}{rl}y & \text{ if }y\in[1,2\sqrt2],\\
\frac 8y & \text{ if } y\in(2\sqrt2,4].
\end{array}$$
Thus the region $f(y)\le x\le g(y)$ for $y\in[1,4]$ can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg\{(x,y):\frac1y\le x\le y, y\in[1,\sqrt2]\bigg\}\cup \bigg\{(x,y):\frac y2\le x\le y, y\in(\sqrt2, 2\sqrt2]\bigg\}\\
&&\cup \bigg\{(x,y):\frac y2\le x\le \frac8y, y\in(2\sqrt2,4]\bigg\}\\
\end{eqnarray}